# Scraping a forum thread: how to calculate the follow-up relationships from css margin attribute?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have been trying really hard on this one.

The target site for my scraping job is an old style forum, in their index page each thread is in a  `<div>` tag, each post is in a `<p>` tag. The follow-up posts will have their left margins indented 20px to indicate the relationship.

```
<div>
  <p style="margin:2px 0 17px 0px; width:705px"><a href="./6368972.html" class="post">original post</a>other stuff</p>
  <p style="margin:2px 0 2px 20px; width:683px"><a href="./6368973.html" class="post">reply post</a>other stuff</p>
  <p style="margin:2px 0 2px 40px; width:661px"><a href="./6368974.html" class="post">reply post</a>other stuff</p>
  ...
</div>
```

I am able to extract many infomation here including title, datetime, nickname, etc, except the follow-up relationships, which I need your help for an effective algorithm. Basically I need to know the post is a reply to which previous post.

My item contains a field for the follow-up relationship, i.e.:
    `reply_to = scrapy.Field()`
where the field should store the url of the reply_to post.

I could extract the value of the left margin for each post as:
`margin = int(div.css('p::attr(style)').re('.* (\d+)px;.*'))`

Also I could calculate the length of the div (i.e., how many total posts are there in a thread).

But really have no idea how might I go from here...

Thank you all!

```
1---------------------       # left margin = 0px; original post
2  -------------------       # left margin = 20px; reply to post 1
3    -----------------       # left margin = 40px; reply to post 2
4  -------------------       # left margin = 20px; reply to post 1, not 3
5    -----------------       # left margin = 40px; reply to post 4, not 2
6      ---------------       # left margin = 60px; reply to post 5
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly you want to do. Can you share desired output concerning provided piece of `HTML` source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but might work:

```
parent = list()
for p in div.xpath('./p'):
    post = dict()
    # do whatever extraction from post here -- title, datetime etc.
    # post['title'] = p.xpath(...)
    # ...
    post['url'] = p.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()

    post['reply_to'] = parent.pop() if len(parent) else None
    margin = int(p.xpath('./@style').re_first('.* (\d+)px;.*'))

    next_p = p.xpath('./following-sibling::p[1]')
    if next_p:
        next_margin = int(next_p.xpath('./@style').re_first('.* (\d+)px;.*'))
        if next_margin > margin:
            # next post is a reply to this post
            if post['reply_to']:
                parent.append(post['reply_to'])
            parent.append(post['url'])
        elif next_margin == margin:
            # next post is a reply to direct parent post
            parent.append(post['reply_to'])
        else:
            # next post if a reply to some distant parent post
            for _ in range((margin - next_margin) / 20 - 1):
                parent.pop()

    yield post
```

Basically it uses stack to store links to parent posts as you go down the thread tree. This way, you don't have to search the tree back and forth to find what post is the current one reply to, but can visit each node only once (well, twice because you always look at the next sibling too).

It could be done easier with XPath and regular expressions, but I think Scrapy selectors use only XPath 1.0 which doesn't support this. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: also honestly i don't understand the underscore `_` in `for _ in range((margin - next_margin) / 20 - 1):`...

Comment: worked like a charm, exactly what I am looking for! minor fix for those of you who need this code, cast `((margin - next_margin) / 20 - 1)` into integer; also you might need to change yield post to something different, at least when I try this in a scrapy shell, code not added to my crawler file just yet. Thank you @Tomáš Linhart !

Comment: @JindanZhou Regarding the underscore - I just need to loop there couple of times but I'm not interested in the particular value that `range` produces. Underscore is a valid identifier for variable and in this use case servers as some kind of dummy. See [here](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc) for better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re:test` xpath expression to match style attribute to some regex:

```
>[1]: sel.xpath('//p[re:test(@style,"margin[^;]+20px")]').extract()
<[1]: ['<p style="margin:2px 0 2px 20px; width:683px"><a href="./6368973.html" class="post">reply post</a>other stuff</p>']
```

'//p[re:test(@style,"margin[^;]20px")]' breakdown:

`//p` - select any `<p>` node
`[re:test(@style,"margin.+20px")]` - test whether @style attribute matches `margin.+20px` regular expression.

Comment: This looks really promising, I'll play this around once I sit at the computer. In the mean time,